# Aggregating a dataframe with dplyr in R based on several dummy variables

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, inner-join

I am using dplyr to aggregate my dataframe, so it shows percentages of people choosing specific protein design tasks by company size. I have different dummy variables for protein design tasks, because this was a multiple choice question in a survey.
I figured out a way to do this, but my code is very long, because I aggregate the data per task and then join all these separate dataframes together into one. *I’m curious whether there is a more elegant (shorter) way to do this?*

```
library(tidyverse)

EarlyAccess <- read_csv("https://dropbox.com/s/antzwk1jh4ldrhi/EarlyAccess_anon.csv?dl=1")

#################### STABILITY ################################################
Proportions_tasks_stability <- EarlyAccess %>% 
  select(size, Improving.stability..generic..thermal..pH.) %>% 
  group_by(size, Improving.stability..generic..thermal..pH.) %>% 
  summarise(count_var_stability=n())%>%
  mutate(total_group_by_size = sum(count_var_stability)) %>%
  mutate(pc_var_stability=count_var_stability/sum(count_var_stability)*100) %>%
  filter(Improving.stability..generic..thermal..pH.=="Improving stability (generic, thermal, pH)") %>%
  select(size, Improving.stability..generic..thermal..pH., pc_var_stability)

######################## ACTIVITY #############################################
Proportions_tasks_activity <- EarlyAccess %>% 
  select(size, Improving.activity ) %>% 
  group_by(size, Improving.activity) %>% 
  summarise(count_var_activity=n())%>%
  mutate(total_group_by_size = sum(count_var_activity)) %>%
  mutate(pc_var_activity=count_var_activity/sum(count_var_activity)*100) %>%
  filter(Improving.activity=="Improving activity") %>%
  select(size, Improving.activity,  pc_var_activity)

######################## BINDING AFFINITY ######################################
Proportions_tasks_binding.affinity<- EarlyAccess %>% 
  select(size, Improving.binding.affinity ) %>% 
  group_by(size, Improving.binding.affinity) %>% 
  summarise(count_var_binding.affinity=n())%>%
  mutate(total_group_by_size = sum(count_var_binding.affinity)) %>%
  mutate(pc_var_binding.affinity=count_var_binding.affinity/sum(count_var_binding.affinity)*100) %>%
  filter(Improving.binding.affinity=="Improving binding affinity") %>%
  select(size, Improving.binding.affinity,  pc_var_binding.affinity)



# Then join them
Protein_design_tasks <- Proportions_tasks_stability %>%
  inner_join(Proportions_tasks_activity, by = "size") %>%
  inner_join(Proportions_tasks_binding.affinity, by = "size")
```

Comment: In short - there will almost certainly be a tidy way of doing this in one piped structure without creating and joining new dataframes. But at the minute it's difficult to know what your task requires without seeing the data. Either a sample of the data or generate some similar data (using `sample` to create randomly generated columns with the same categories) and post here for us to try out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the datafile you provided, this should give the percentages of the selected category within each column for each size:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  read_csv("https://dropbox.com/s/antzwk1jh4ldrhi/EarlyAccess_anon.csv?dl=1")

df |>
  group_by(size) |>
  summarise(
    pc_var_stability = sum(
      Improving.stability..generic..thermal..pH. == "Improving stability (generic, thermal, pH)",
      na.rm = TRUE
    ) / n() * 100,
    pc_var_activity = sum(Improving.activity == "Improving activity",
                          na.rm = TRUE) / n() * 100,
    pc_var_binding.affinity = sum(
      Improving.binding.affinity == "Improving binding affinity",
      na.rm = TRUE
    ) / n() * 100
  )
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   size       pc_var_stability pc_var_activity pc_var_binding.affinity
#>   <chr>                 <dbl>           <dbl>                   <dbl>
#> 1 1000-10000             43.5            47.8                    34.8
#> 2 10000+                 65              65                      70  
#> 3 11-50                  53.8            53.8                    46.2
#> 4 2-10                   51.1            46.8                    46.8
#> 5 200-1000               64.7            52.9                    52.9
#> 6 50-200                 42.1            42.1                    36.8
#> 7 Just me                48.5            39.4                    54.5
```

Looking at your data, each column has either the string value you're testing for or NA, so you could make it even shorter/tidier just by counting non-NAs in relevant columns:

```r
df |>
  group_by(size) |>
  summarise(across(
    c(
      Improving.stability..generic..thermal..pH.,
      Improving.activity,
      Improving.binding.affinity
    ),
    \(val) 100 * sum(!is.na(val)) / n()
  ))
```

If what you're aiming to do is summarise across all columns then the latter method may work best - there are several ways of specifying which columns you want and so you don't necessarily need to type all names and values in. You might also find it clearest to make calculating and formatting all percentages a named function to call:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  read_csv("https://dropbox.com/s/antzwk1jh4ldrhi/EarlyAccess_anon.csv?dl=1", 
           show_col_types = FALSE)


perc_nonmissing <- function(val) {
  sprintf("%.1f%%", 100 * sum(!is.na(val)) / n())
}


df |>
  group_by(size) |>
  summarise(across(-c(1:2), perc_nonmissing))

#> # A tibble: 7 × 12
#>   size   Disco…¹ Searc…² Under…³ Impro…⁴ Impro…⁵ Impro…⁶ Impro…⁷ Impro…⁸ Impro…⁹
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 1000-… 21.7%   17.4%   43.5%   47.8%   39.1%   43.5%   30.4%   39.1%   39.1%  
#> 2 10000+ 40.0%   55.0%   55.0%   65.0%   70.0%   65.0%   20.0%   30.0%   40.0%  
#> 3 11-50  30.8%   26.9%   42.3%   53.8%   38.5%   53.8%   15.4%   30.8%   38.5%  
#> 4 2-10   38.3%   40.4%   48.9%   46.8%   36.2%   51.1%   23.4%   31.9%   42.6%  
# etc.
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! Would you like to have a csv file with the data or would you prefer me to copy and paste the data? I'm relatively new to StackOverflow, so don't yet know what is customary. If you want a csv with the sample data, see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/antzwk1jh4ldrhi/EarlyAccess_anon.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Great! I've put it in the answer and for me it's producing a table summarising percentage values correctly as far as I can see. Give it a try and see if it outputs what you expect it to.

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thanks so much! This is super helpful. I was thinking last night that a good solution may be to write some kind of function or loop, so this is a great suggestion. 
Your code (with the second option !is.na) works perfectly if I just use it going directly from the sample file, but when I work with the real data file, it doesn’t work, because the empty values are not recognised as missing, so I I have to define them as missing first (and then it works great). Is there anything you’ve specified in reading in the data that does this automatically?

Comment: Also, my ultimate goal is to create a plot with these percentages using ggplot and in my original data I still had the variables showing the protein task, so I could map them onto the x variable in ggplot and separate variables for the percentages. Is there a way to keep the original variables (e.g. Improving.stability..generic..thermal..pH. 
Improving.activity 
Improving.binding.affinity) or is it easier if I just append them back after aggregating? [This is what I’d like to have as a result.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w82ii32qndi3j44/protein_design_tasks.csv?dl=0).

Comment: [And this is the ggplot code I’m using](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3johpvv6apuz523/Gggplot%20code%20protein%20design%20tasks.R?dl=0)

Comment: A few things I'd suggest! If you read using `readr::read_csv` it will do NAs for you; if using `read.csv` give it the argument `na.strings = ""`. To graph, I'd suggested using `pivot_longer` and making two columns for all results, rather than two columns each. I've put some example code recreating your graph with fewer lines here: [rtraining.co.uk/graph_for_so_question.html](https://rtraining.co.uk/graph_for_so_question.html)

Comment: Have a try with those parts and see if they make sense and you can figure out how they work! If you're still having troubles then new questions on here or move to discussion might be best - hard to give more help in the comments section :)

Comment: Amazing, thank you again Andy, super useful! This is so much more elegant, because it’s a lot less code. Thanks for being such a generous teacher.